# Use layout.html template to select all files in a folder [Sphinx]

Tags: html, python-sphinx

I am using Sphinx to build documentation currently. The template currently builds the documentation with a certain HTML structure. For all files inside a sub-directory(let's call it folder X), I would like to use a different HTML structure.

Is there any way to find if a file belongs to folder X or it's sub-directories?

One method I thought of is to find the path between the documentation root and the current file. If "folder X" is inside the path, that means the current file is inside folder X (or a sub-directory of it)

Comment: Look into customizing Sphinx themes and Jinja2 docs for conditional logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More of a workaround than anything.

I used the path from the current file to a file inside folder X (i.e. folder X/test.html). Any path that has the substring "folder X/" is not found in folder X.

```
{% if "folder X/" not in pathto('folder X/test') %}
```